# NodeJS with Express as a server for HTML --> PDF generation. Can it be efficient?

Tags: node.js, multithreading, puppeteer

I know about the event loop and the single threaded nature of NodeJS. Given that, do you think it is a good idea to go ahead and develop a NodeJS/Express service that we can use to convert HTML parts to PDF pages?

We are thinking about Puppeteer. I already used it and it works great, but I'm not sure if each user in the organization would have to be waiting for the event loop because each request would keep the process busy until the end?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Event Loop

The event loop is what takes care of the "single-threaded event-driven" nature of JavaScript, meaning that asynchronous (JavaScript) code that needs to be executed will be put in a queue and executed one after another (by the loop) instead of using a more classic multi-threading approach. For more information on this topic I recommend [this great video explanation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ).

The event loop is not really related to your problem, as most of the work happens asynchronously inside the browser (and not inside the Node.js runtime). That means that your puppeteer script will most of the time wait for the browser to return results.

Consider a simple line like this:

```js
await browser.newPage();
```

What does this actually do? It sends the command to the browser (running in another process) to open a page. The actual work is happening inside the browser, not in your Node.js environment. The same goes for basically all puppeteer functions. Therefore, the "main work" is not happening inside your Node.js environment and therefore the event loop is not related to your problem.

#### Implemenation

What you are describing is absolutely doable with puppeteer and Node.js. Let's consider this example code which should get you started:

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

app.get('/pdf', async (req, res) => { // Call /pdf?url=... to create a PDF of the provided URL
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(req.query.url); // URL is given by the user
    const pdfBuffer = await page.pdf();

    // Respond with the PDF
    res.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type': 'application/pdf',
        'Content-Length': pdfBuffer.length
    });
    res.end(pdfBuffer);

    await browser.close();
});

app.listen(4000);
```

This will offer an API to generate a PDF of a URL. Every request will open a browser, open a new page, navigate to the given URL and return a PDF to the user. Thanks to the asynchronous environment of JavaScript, this will happen fully in parallel. As long as your machine can handle the number of parallel open browsers, you are fine.

#### Further improvement

While the given script works, you should keep in mind that too many requets might quickly consume too much memory/CPU due to many open browsers and therefore lead to resource problems. To improve the implementation, you want to use a pool of puppeteer resources to handle the traffic. For that you might want to look into [puppeteer-cluster](https://github.com/thomasdondorf/puppeteer-cluster) (disclaimer: I'm the author) which provides you with pool of browser instances and will allow to limit the number of running browsers. The library can handle this use case easily. There is actually an [example](https://github.com/thomasdondorf/puppeteer-cluster/blob/master/examples/express-screenshot.js) online for this exact use case (however, it generates screenshots instead of PDFs).

Comment: Thanks for your great answer. I wanted to ask you something: should I `cluster.close()` at the end of my script? I checked the example you provide and there isn't any cluster closing happening..

Comment: @rmartrenado If you are writing a server, you don't need to close the cluster. The cluster itself will take care of managing the browsers for you. Only close the cluster if you know there are no more jobs incoming.

Comment: From your point of view: Why should I choose the `puppeteer-cluster` solution instead of just creating a simple server balanced by PM2? One of my concerns is that using your library I can't pass any launching parameters to puppeteer (like headless, or devtools, because launch is being re-implemented)

Comment: @rmartrenado Yes, this is possible ([API](https://github.com/thomasdondorf/puppeteer-cluster#clusterlaunchoptions)), example: `Cluster.launch({ puppeteerOptions: { headless: false } })` You don't need to use it if you are not expecting a lot of load. But one user starting 20 requests in parallel might crash your server if you are not limiting it through a pool somehow. You can also use PM2, but this adds another layer of complexity to your application IMHO (and I'm not sure how rate-limiting would work there TBH).

Comment: Simply majestic. Thanks Thomas, and sorry, because I didn't notice that part of the docs. I got my code pretty advanced already :D

Comment: @rmartrenado No worries, I might really need to make it more obvious. You are not the first one to ask ;)

Comment: Hi again. Do you think you could try to help me on: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56018295/puppeteer-cluster-closing-page-when-i-interact-with-it