# puppeteer cluster _ how to prevent close page?

Tags: puppeteer, mutation-observers, puppeteer-cluster

I am glad to find the puppeteer cluster. this library made life easy on crawling and automation tasks.tnx to [Thomas Dondorf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5627599/thomas-dondorf).

according to the author of the puppeteer cluster, when a task finished page will be closed [immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56027604/5677187).this is good by the way. but what about some cases that you need to page will be open?

my use case:
I will try to explain briefly:

there is some activity on the page that in the background a socket is involved in for sending some data to the front .this  data changes the dome and I need to capture that.

this is my code :

```
async function runCrawler(){
    const links = [
      "foo.com/barSome324",
      "foo.com/barSome22",
      "foo.com/barSome1",
      "foo.com/barSome765",
  
  
    ]

    const cluster = await Cluster.launch({
      concurrency: Cluster.CONCURRENCY_CONTEXT,
      workerCreationDelay: 5000,
      puppeteerOptions:{args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox'], headless:false},
      maxConcurrency: numCPUs,
    });
   
    await cluster.task(async ({ page, data: url }) => {
      await crawler(page, url)
      
    });
    for(link of links){
      await cluster.queue(link);
  
    }
    await cluster.idle();
  await cluster.close();
  }
```

and this is the crawler logic in page section:

```
module.exports.crawler = async(page, link)=>{
  await page.goto(link, { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' })
  await page.waitForTimeout(10000)
  await page.waitForSelector('#dbp')
    try {
          // method to be executed;
          setInterval(async()=>{
            const tables=await page.evaluate(async()=>{
               /// data I need to catch in every 30 seconds
            });
            
            
          },30000)

      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
      }
    
    
}
```

I searched And find out in js we can capture DOM changes with [mutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver#Methods) .and tried this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54109078/puppeteer-wait-for-page-dom-updates-respond-to-new-items-that-are-added-after) . but did not work either.page will be closed with this error:

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Protocol error
> (Runtime.callFunctionOn): Session closed. Most likely the page has
> been closed.

so I have two options here:

1.mutationObserver

2.set interval for every 30 seconds evaluates the page itself.

but they did not suit my needs. so any idea how to overcome this problem?

Comment: If you use the mutationObserver, i think you should use the page.waitForFunction method rather than evaluating in a loop without ending. Hope this helped you then.